# Trying to make a python dictionary from a file but I keep getting errors like 'too many values to unpack'

Tags: python, file, function, dictionary

I have a text file saved in notepad but moved into my python folder that has a three letter acronym for a country on the left and then about four or five spaces to the right it has the country that corresponds to it like so:

> AFG    Afghanistan
>   ARM    Armenia
>   etc.

I need the dictionary to use the three letters be the key and country be the value.  It has every country that participates in the Olympics. Here's what my code looks like thus far:

```
def country(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName,'r')
    countryDict = {}
    for line in infile:
        key,value = line.split()
        countryDict[key] = value
    print(countryDict)
    return countryDict
country('CountryCodes.txt')
```

Answer (score 6):

Most likely some of the countries (e.g. New Zealand) have more than one word in their names and so `split()` is returning more than two items, but you're trying to assign the results to two variables regardless. Limit the `split` to one:

```
key, value = line.split(None, 1)
```

If you find you're getting excess whitespace at the end, throw a `strip()` in there:

```
key, value = line.strip().split(None, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to split description from a country code... The following will cater for empty descriptions or descriptions of more than one word

```
with open('input') as fin:
    country_lookup = dict(line.strip().partition(' ')[::2] for line in fin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this amazing function instead:

```
def parse_country_codes(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return dict(line.split(None, 1) for line in f if line)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is one of your lines in your file has more than one space, so a line may look like this:

```
hi hello hey
```

When doing `line.split()`, you're getting:

```
['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
```

Which you're trying to assign to two variables, but there are 3 elements in the list. Thus the error.

To avoid this, you would have to either refine your split so it only splits once, or split once only:

```
key, value = line.split(' ', 1)
```

Or, if you're using python 3, you can unpack the rest of the list to the value:

```
key, *value = line.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your lines must have more than one space so `split()` returns more than the two values expected by `key,value = line.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Some countries will have more than one word as the name so you end up with multiple value fields, try:

```
def country(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName,'r')
    countryDict = {}
    for line in infile:
       key = line[0:3]
       value = line[3:].strip()
       countryDict[key] = value
    print(countryDict)
    return countryDict
country('CountryCodes.txt')
```

Comment: your code compiled and ran but when I had it print it gave me this massive block of weird code like so: {'\x00A\x00': 'R\x00E\x00\t\x00U\x00N\x00I\x00T\x00E\x00D\x00 \x00A\x00R\x00A\x00B\x00 \x00E\x00M\x00I\x00R\x00A\x00T\x00E\x00S\x00', '\x00V\x00': 'I\x00R\x00\t\x00V\x00I\x00R\x00G\x00I\x00N\x00 \x00I\x00S\x00L\x00A\x00N\x00D\x00S\x00 \x00(\x00U\x00.\x00S\x00.\x00)\x00', '\x00\n':

Comment: It is python so it doesn't compile but it looks like you have run it with a binary file as CountryCodes.txt