# ValueError when trying to add to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, file-io, dictionary

So I have a file in this format

```
CountryCode   CountryName
USA           United States
```

What I want to do is make a dictionary with the code as the key, and the country name as the value.

I have a function which has the intent of doing that

```
def country(string):
    '''reads the contents of a file into a string and closes it.'''

    #open the file
    countryDict = {}
    fin = open(string, 'r')
    for eachline in fin:
        code, country = eachline.split()
        countryDict[code] = country

    print (countryDict)


    return countryDict
```

However, when I try to run it, I get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

Any reason why this code doesn't work?  A similar program that I had that created user names using code like this worked.

Code for username program for reference, this works, why doesn't the above:

```
def main():
    print ("This program creates a file of usernames from a")
    print ("file of names.")

    # get the file names
    infileName = input("What file are the names in? ")
    outfileName = input("What file should the usernames go in? ")

    # open the files
    infile = open(infileName, 'r')
    outfile = open(outfileName, 'w')
    # process each line of the input file
    for line in infile:
        # get the first and last names from line
        first, last = line.split()
        # create a username
        uname = (first[0]+last[:7]).lower()
        # write it to the output file
        print(uname, file=outfile)


    # close both files

    infile.close()

    outfile.close()


    print("Usernames have been written to", outfileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17653954/1971805 Not a dupe (kinda), but coincidence much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about when `line` is:

```
USA           United States
```

When you split it, it would create:

```
['USA', 'United', 'States']
```

And when you go to do `first, last = line.split()`, it will try to put three values into two variables (hence the error).

To prevent this, you can split once:

```
>>> first, last = 'USA           United States'.split(None, 1)
>>> first
'USA'
>>> last
'United States'
```

Comment: +1. Also, you shouldn't assume that your file is formatted correctly. Instead, you should write code that handles things like blank lines and lines with only one word, etc.

Comment: @JoelCornett I know, but the programming practice I've been taught is to add basic functionality (assume at this stage of the game that the user(s) will put in perfect input) first then add in error checking and other bells and whistles once the basic needs of the program have been met.

Comment: @user1768884: You should always (from the beginning) incorporate error *checking* and logging capabilities. Graceful error *handling* is functionality that you can implement later however.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using regex

```
def country(string):
    fin = open(string, 'r')
    pat = r'\s*([A-Za-z0-9]*)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\s]*?)\n'
    tup = re.findall(pat, fin)
    return dict(tup)
```